# action_mailer.delivery_method in test.rb not being followed

Tags: cucumber

I've noticed my Cucumber tests started to take a loooong time to run, and eventually I realized it's because it's trying to connect to an smtp server when I use mailers. I already have the following line on my test.rb file:

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

However, that setting doesn't seem to be followed. If I remove the line below from my mailer.rb file, then it all works fine:

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

Of course if I remove that line, then the production version won't work anymore...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Being set somewhere after the test.rb is run.

You should configure your production mailer details inside production.rb

Comment: Yup... I had the settings in a config/initializers/mailer.rb file, instead of production.rb. I guess wherever I learned about mailers a few months ago was just plainly wrong. Thanks!  :)